# Settings defined in website scopes are ignored

Tags: multistore, magento-2.1.3, system-configuration

Since one month, I set up a **multistore** platform under **Magento 2**. Everything worked perfectly under **version 2.1.2** but since I updated it in **2.1.3** two weeks ago I got a big problem :
All settings defined in website scopes are ignored.
For example, if I set a `minimal order amount` for one of my websites, **I can order normally without any restrictions (not normal). But if I defined this setting in the default scope the restriction work.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a core bug in 2.1.3 - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7943

There is a fix for the issue here - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Store/Model/Config/Processor/Fallback.php#L109

To save going to the link, the change you need to make is to vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Config/Processor/Fallback.php

Change this

```
/**
 * Retrieve Website Config
 *
 * @param array $websites
 * @param int $id
 * @return array
 */
private function getWebsiteConfig(array $websites, $id)
{
    foreach ($this->websiteData as $website) {
        if ($website['website_id'] == $id) {
            $code = $website['website_id'];
            return isset($websites[$code]) ? $websites[$code] : [];
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

To

```
/**
 * Retrieve Website Config
 *
 * @param array $websites
 * @param int $id
 * @return array
 */
private function getWebsiteConfig(array $websites, $id)
{
    foreach ($this->websiteData as $website) {
        if ($website['website_id'] == $id) {
            $code = $website['code'];
            return isset($websites[$code]) ? $websites[$code] : [];
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

Note the line

```
$code = $website['code'];
```

Ideally you should do this as a patch - see http://jamescowie.me/blog/2016/12/Composer-Magento-Patches/

Comment: I took the complete code form the Github and replace my "Fallback.php" file. It work perfectly :D ! Thank you sooo much !

Comment: Glad it worked. Please be careful that when you next do an update, your changes will be overwritten. I imagine that fix will be in the next release but even so it's worth documenting what changes you've made in case.