# base currency not working

Tags: magento2, multistore, currency

I have set up **three websites and allocated different base currencies**. 
However, it it not appearing correctly on the frontend.

Also on the catalog page of admin, I cannot input in different base currencies.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the issue that

[Settings defined in website scopes are ignored](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153241/settings-defined-in-website-scopes-are-ignored)

Once this was fixed, it is working.